# Creating fields in attributes table using other layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-processing

I want to create a grid over my map and for each box in that grid I want to record attributes from other layers in my project; or I want to add columns in the attributes table for the grid layer where these columns contain data about other layers in my project.

For example if my grid layer is named **grid** and I have another layer called **location** which consists of points, then I want to add a column to the **grid** attributes table that gives me the total number of points in **location** that coincide with each box of **grid**. This is a simple example, but I need to do this for many layers to create many fields in the **grid** attributes table. My hope is export this attributes table for economic analysis.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Count points in polygon` tool which, which from its name it counts the point in each polygon, as you can see below:

[image]

Just seach in Processing toolbox for `Count points in polygon` tool and you will find it.

[image]